# Fatal error: Call to undefined function bind_param()

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to retrieve student name from database using mysql LIKE, i have following form

```
  <form action="search.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search-input">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
  </form>
```

And my search.php

```
<?php 
        require_once 'db.php';
        if (isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search'])) {
            $search_param = trim($_POST['search']);

            $slct_search = $db->prepare("SELECT student_name FROM student_details WHERE student_name LIKE ?") or die($db->error);
            $slct_search = bind_param('s', $search_param);
            $slct_search->execute();        
            $res = $slct_search->get_result();  
            if($res->num_rows) {            
                while ($result = $res->fetch_object()) {
                    echo $result->student_name;
                }
            } else {
                echo 'OOPS we had a problem';
            }   
        }
    ?>
```

When I click the submit button i am receiving following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function bind_param() in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\sel\search.php on line 7

Comment: @SuperDJ my question is unique, please read the error message and compare with you are referred, also see the Chris Maggs statement his answer, Please don't down vote

Comment: have you tried: `$slct_search->bind_param('s', $search_param);`? also note that you might use `trim()` but it still leaves you open to SQL-injection

Comment: Is it now working? Because you have changed it in your question. Noone can see what's wrong so you can undo the edit so I add it as answer so you can accept it?

Comment: sure, but please upvote

Comment: Not related to OP's exact issue, but I got this error by accidentally using a period instead of -> and this was the first result on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$slct_search->bind_param('s', $search_param);
```

Also note that you might use `trim()` but it still leaves you open to SQL-injection. Try to do someting like:

```
$db->real_escape_string( trim( $_POST['search'] ) );
```

Read about some other escapeing here:

- [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)
- [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)
- [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: *"Try to do someting like:

$db->real_escape_string( trim( $_POST['search'] ) );"* - A prepared statement is better than `real_escape_string()`. Even that can be exploited, believe it or not.

Comment: *"Read about some other escapeing here:"* - `strip_tags()` and `htmlentities()` don't do much to protect against an SQL injection. Again; a prepared statement will take care of all that, without the use of those extra functions.

Comment: Using `LIKE` requires more. What you're doing here will only search for exact matches.

Answer (score 1):

Please use - > for the bind_param

Use this $slct_search - >bind_param

Instead of this $slct_search = bind_param